# XCode 4.6: iOS 6.1 - CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString errors when validating

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, xcode4.6, ios6.1

[image]

I've changed the "Bundle version" and "Bundle versions string, short" values seemingly a hundred times with all different variations 1.2, 1.201, 2, 1.2.1...etc.  Also, I've changed the version numbers in the target > Summary tab.

Has anyone had this problem when validating an archive, or trying to upload via the old Application Loader? I was also getting the same looking error for "CFBundleVersion."  The last update to the app was v1.13, so I'm not sure why 1.2 is a problem.  It this an XCode 4.6 bug?

Comment: have you tried deleting the project's derived data, and restarting xcode?

Comment: 2 is less than 13. You can't go from 1.13 to 1.2. Your only options are 1.13.x, 1.14 (or higher), or 2.x.

Comment: As @rmaddy mentioned you should try with `1.14`. But if you have already tried with `1.201` I am not sure if that could be the actual reason.

Comment: @maddy (1.2 > 1.13) == YES other than in the mad parsing of Xcode <grin>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to user's comments and some, well, problem solving...

When I downloaded XCode 4.6, I use SmartSVN/VisualSVN to manage versioning.  When I updated SmartSVN to the latest version, I got an dialog saying XCode doesn't support the SVN version (which is the latest version), so I thought to commit after I changed the bundle versions in the .plist.  Blammo...bundle validated and submitted!

Here is what I learned that really did the trick.  XCode 4.6 must have new versioning requirements, as the bundle version was still set to 1.0 when I tried the first time.  I've submitted a version 1.0, 1.1, 1.12, and 1.13...so XCode must have only been checking the versions in the TARGETS > Summary tab.  Those were always set to the appropriated version.

The kicker is that I didn't know XCode sees 1.2 < 1.13.  As soon as I changed the values in the .plist AND the values in the TARGETS > Summary tab to "1.20," the bundle successfully validated, as 1.20 > 1.2 and 1.20 > 1.13...thanks for shining the light guys.

NOTE: If you are using a version controller, make sure you commit before building if you get that XCode alert about not supporting the SVN version.